# C# extract escape character from string

Tags: c#, string, text, escaping, backslash

I'm reading an encoded string into memory and decode it.
The string is something like **"test\file1.txt"**.

Normally, C# would see this as string literal **"test \\ file1.txt"**, correctly assigning an escape character to the backslash-char.

In this case, C# sees the slash as an escape character for the f from file. ("\f").

I can't use the **Replace(@"\", @"\")** method of string, because C# doesn't find "\", it only finds "\f". The filename is completely variable, so I can't use **Replace(@"\f", @"\f")** either...

How would I proceed with this in-memory string and add a slash, so that the string is a valid path?

**The string is just loaded from a text-file and passed through a decoder.**

```
public static string Decode(string inp)
{
    byte[] ToDecode = System.Convert.FromBase64String(inp);
    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ToDecode);
}
```

**This is where I actually use the string (which is called 'A')**

```
foreach (string A in Attchmnts)
    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_AttachmentsPath + @"\" + A));
```

**If I check the contents of the Attachment, via immediate, this is the result:**

```
?_AttachmentsPath + @"\" + A
"\\\\BUPC1537\\MailServer\\Attachments\\test\file2.txt"
```

**I have manually encoded the string by calling following method in immediate (and then pasting that data into an XML document):**

```
public static string Encode(string inp)
{
    byte[] ToEncode = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inp);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(ToEncode);
}

//Immediate code
?Utils.Encoder.Encode("test\file2.txt")
"dGVzdAxpbGUyLnR4dA=="
```

Comment: Please show your code. What you say is happening doesn't happen when you decode a string. There must be something else going on here. Most likely, the string already got written incorrectly into the file.

Comment: Seems that you really get testfile1.txt when reading the string

Comment: Added the decoder code.

Comment: I am still certain that the string got persisted incorrectly into the file. Where does that file come from?

Comment: So, where do you call `Decode`?

Comment: As you can see, the "\" before the "f" is not excaped, so this is really only one char : '\f'. You need to verify why you have this behaviour.

Comment: Is the string `UTF8` encoded before you `base64` encode it?

Comment: The file is a test example that I encoded, using the same procedure. It is just test\file2.txt encoded to Base64. 
Unfortunately, Base64 seems to decode with \f as a single char, instead of \ as a single char...

Comment: @Jodrell The string resides in an XML, which is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: @Recipe: Please understand that what you say is *not true*. It is not the decoding at fault nor Base64. The fault lies with the code that created the string before encoding it or writing it to a file. Most likely, you forgot the `@` in front of a part of the string when you created your sample file. Please show the exact code you used to create that file.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have added the way I encoded the string. The text was literally copied and pasted by me into an xml-file.

Comment: @Recipe: Please see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17675616/572644).

Comment: If you do `var test = @"test\file2.txt";` then evaluate `test == Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test))));` you'll find it evaluates to `true`. In fact, you'll find it evaluates to true whatever value you use for `test`.

Comment: @Jodrell you are correct. It was the missing verbatim character that made such a mess of the encoded string!

Comment: well, you tested an edge case and proved it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected all along, the code that creates the file doesn't correctly escape the backslash.

Fix it by doing so, either by using a verbatim string:

```
Utils.Encoder.Encode(@"test\file2.txt")
```

or by explicitly escaping the backslash:

```
Utils.Encoder.Encode("test\\file2.txt")
```

Comment: I'm going to try that right away!
edit: What a mistake to make...thanks very much Daniel Hilgart.